# Follower bug: can't progress

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I tried to post this question on Battle.net, but because I'm on PS3 I can't link my game and it won't let me. Thanks Blizzard.

I've just unlocked Nightmare mode and started playing through on it. I got to the cathedral LV 3 where you meet the Templar, and freed him. He runs over to his belongings, but then just stands there. Doesn't matter if I have a follower already or not. So I can't get past the spikes to get through to the next bit of the quest. Tried restarting the game, quitting out, coming back with different / no followers, but to no avail. Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried to restart the chapter/level from scratch?

Comment: Do you open the chest he's stopping near? Is the chest even there?

Comment: Don't seem to be able to interact with either him or the chest. Will try restarting the whole chapter later, see if that helps. :/

Answer (score 1):

The steps you need to take are:

1. Make sure you killed all of the enemies that are guarding the chest.
2. Restart the quest via leaving the game and selecting that quest again. You should hit "save and close" rather than join game to make sure.
3. If you are still having issues, make sure that you talk to the Templar after you free him from the circle. He will have an exclamation mark above his head.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , what I did to fix it was leave the dungeon , exit the game to title screen ,went back in and then I let him kill one of the priests and bam fixed and I could interact wih him